Identity for generators of $SU(N)$ in the adjoint representation
For the generators of $SU(N)$ in the  fundamental representation, $T_{i j}^a$, the following identity holds
$$T_{i j}^a T_{k \ell}^a=\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta_{i \ell} \delta_{j k}-\frac{1}{N} \delta_{i j} \delta_{k \ell}\right).$$
Does a similar identity hold for the generators in the adjoint representation, i.e., for $-if_{abc}$?

Surely this depends on your choice of generators.   After all, one could take arbitrary combos of generators and still get another generator.

@ZeroTheHero I would prefer a reference in this regard. That is why i asked.

You have digested this, presumably. Your normalization of the adjoint was off, which I corrected. You are asking for (42),
$$
f_{ab}^{~~~e}f_{cd}^{~~~e}= {2\over N} (\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}- \delta_{ad}\delta_{bc} ) + d_{ac}^{~~~e}d_{bd}^{~~~e}-d_{bc}^{~~~e}d_{ad}^{~~~e}~~.
$$
Summed-over indices have been raised by a flat metric for legibility. Check the symmetries and contractions, and the trivial N=2 limit.
Macfarlane et al, 1968 is a must.

Edit in response to comment
Since the structure constants are antisymmetric, multiplying both sides by -1 and relabelling/rearranging indices readily yields
$$
(F^a)_{bc}(F^a)_{pq}= {2\over N} (\delta_{cq}\delta_{bp}- \delta_{cp}\delta_{bq} ) + d_{bp}^{~~~a}d_{dq}^{~~~a}-d_{cp}^{~~~a}d_{bq}^{~~~a}~~.
$$

Yeah but the adjoint generator is defined as in Eq. (32) of your file. And that is what precisely follows the correct Lie algebra. So the identity you wrote is not what I am looking for. I am looking for an identity for $(F^{a}){bc}(F^{a}){pq}$. The above what you have quoted is $(F^{a}){be}(F^{c}){de}$ in their notation.

Edited in response to your index shuffling/renaming request. You were supposed to digest the cited reference.

+1, I don't know why there was a -1 to this answer since it perfectly answered the question, even before the Edit.

@CosmasZachos Don't be so quick to judge. This was merely to confirm if things were just as hopeless as I was afraid they are. And, unfortunately, they are.

Why hopeless? For N =3, where the d's are available, it is tractable, no?
